# value to object isn't assigned by map function

Tags: node.js, array.prototype.map

Can somebody tell me why the returned object is not assigned with the value?
With the moment libary I want to format the datestamp into a quarter value so I can display this nicely in the front-end. This is the controller that handles the request from the front-end and send back by Express.

```
  exports.getHistoricalOpp = async (req, res) => {
  const hisOpps = await Opportunity.find({original_id: req.params.id, deleted_opportunity: true});
  const modHisOpps = hisOpps.map(async (el) => {
    const formatQuarter = await moment(el.timing).format("Q");
    el.quarter = formatQuarter;
    console.log(el.timing);
    return el;
  });
  await Promise.all(modHisOpps).then(data => {
    console.log('response',data);
    res.json(data);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

response:

```
[ { _id: 5b61bc933d93fc2dc0a3d11a,
[]     account_name: 'Fieten Olie',
[]     name: 'PriceCast',
[]     amount: 5000,
[]     timing: 2018-09-30T00:00:00.000Z,
[]     scotsman: 63,
[]     weighted_amount: 3150,
[]     status: 'afspraak gepland',
[]     order_received: false,
[]     deleted_opportunity: true,
[]     sales_rep: 5b47a9af4977815d4c7a0bc2,
[]     created_on: 2018-08-01T13:58:43.523Z,
[]     original_id: 5b61bc933d93fc2dc0a3d11a,
[]     __v: 0 },
[]   { _id: 5b61bca03d93fc2dc0a3d11b,
[]     account_name: 'Fieten Olie',
[]     name: 'PriceCast',
[]     amount: 4000,
[]     timing: 2018-09-30T00:00:00.000Z,
[]     scotsman: 63,
[]     weighted_amount: 2520,
[]     status: 'afspraak gepland',
[]     order_received: false,
[]     original_id: 5b61bc933d93fc2dc0a3d11a,
[]     deleted_opportunity: true,
[]     sales_rep: 5b47a9af4977815d4c7a0bc2,
[]     created_on: 2018-08-01T13:58:56.289Z,
[]     __v: 0 },
[]   { _id: 5b61bca83d93fc2dc0a3d11c,
[]     account_name: 'Fieten Olie',
[]     name: 'PriceCast',
[]     amount: 4000,
[]     timing: 2018-09-30T00:00:00.000Z,
[]     scotsman: 75,
[]     weighted_amount: 3000,
[]     status: 'afspraak gepland',
[]     order_received: false,
[]     original_id: 5b61bc933d93fc2dc0a3d11a,
[]     deleted_opportunity: true,
[]     sales_rep: 5b47a9af4977815d4c7a0bc2,
[]     created_on: 2018-08-01T13:59:04.810Z,
[]     __v: 0 } ]
```

the expexted outcome is: element.quarter = 3.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I try it with mocked data, `quarter` is added to the object. One note though, you are `await`ing non-asynchronous code, which needlessly complicated things. There is no reason to `await` the return from `moment` -- it's synchronous.

Comment: It's strange because when I `console.log(data[1].quarter)` it logs the formated text. But when I log the res array there is no quarter on the object.